# how to prevent ir receiver from waking computer

Tags: windows-media-center, remote-control

I have an HP dv4 notebook, which has an ir receiver on the front.  I want to configure it so that no matter what, IR signals will not trigger vista media center to start.  It currently starts whether the computer is on or in sleep mode in response to MCE remote commands being directed at another computer in the room.  how do I make the notebook ignore the ir commands?

Ive tried uninstalling the IR tranceiver device, whenever I reboot windows reinstalls the drivers for it and im back where i started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low-tech solutions for high-tech problems. Don't laugh. Cut a strip of duct tape and paste it over the IR window. I had to resort to this on an old Compaq notebook that kept trying to transfer files whenever my Treo came near.

Comment: I'm certainly not laughing, in fact I tried this before.  The only problem is that it's my wife's laptop, and the WAF on the tape is quite low.  Maybe I can sell her on some black paint.  If so, you win :)

Comment: Black nail polish.  4 coats, and its IR-opaque.  Problem solved, thanks much.

Comment: "The WAF on the tape is quite low." - LOL, classic!

Answer (score 2):

no option in the BIOS to disable the IR receiver?

Comment: no, this bios is pretty slim.  no options to enable or disable devices

Comment: thought so ... that's Hewlett-Packard for ya :(

Comment: and you say disabling is not an option in the device manager? have you tried DevCon? http://www.robvanderwoude.com/devcon.php

Comment: devcon gives me a "disable failed" message when i try to disable the device.  the Disable button is greyed out in device manager.

Answer (score 2):

In Device Manager, highlight the IR device and right click. Select properties. Navigate to the Power Management tab (might be labeled differently in XP) and uncheck the box that says "Allow this device to wake the computer" and click apply.

Comment: No can do.  The only tabs available on the property page for the device are General, Driver, and Details, all of which are inquiry-only.  No Power Management tab, nothing I can update about a power management setting.  I'm beginning to think that HP really doesnt want this thing disabled for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried steps like these (from a [message board post](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/psg/board/message?board.id=TouchSmartPC&message.id=795#M795)):

1) Disable automatic driver downloads:
- Start menu -> Right click Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings (top left) -> Hardware -> Windows Update Drivers Settings -> Select "Never check for drivers when I connect a device." -> OK -> Apply -> OK

2) Turn off SSDP Discovery:
- Start menu -> Type in "services.msc" without quotes and press Enter -> Scroll to "SSDP Discovery" -> Right click and select Properties -> Change Startup Type to "Disabled" -> Apply -> OK

3) Uninstall ENE CIR Receiver:
- Start menu -> Right click Computer -> Manage -> Device Manager -> Click the + beside Human Interface Devices -> Right click "ENE CIR Receiver" and select Uninstall -> MAKE SURE TO CHECK THE UNINSTALL SOFTWARE BOX ON THE PROMPT (this will take the Microsoft eHome Infrared Trasceiver with it) -> OK -> Let the uninstall take place -> Reboot the computer

4) Preventing installation of IR device drivers:
- Upon reboot you will receive a prompt asking you if you want to install the device drivers -> SELECT "NEVER FOR THIS DEVICE"

5) Turn ON SSDP Discovery:
- Follow directions from earlier and select "Manual" from the drop down menu (Startup Type) -> Apply -> OK

---

Have you tried just disabling the IR transceiver?

Comment: there is no option in the device manager to disable it, only uninstall it.  ill dig around further, but i havent been able to find anything to disable it with.

Comment: Have you tried the steps I just added to my answer above?

Comment: (May not be the exact steps and IR device may be different.)

Comment: I tried this, it made windows not boot after I disabled the services.

Comment: Did you only disable the SSDP Discovery service?